# SQL mistake AS after Where IN

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i wrote some SQLs and have some problems.

```
SELECT uri, k.score_x
  FROM uris
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id, SUM(x) AS score_x
      FROM keywords
      WHERE key = 'key1' OR
        key='key2' OR
        key='key3' OR
        key='key4'
      GROUP BY id
      HAVING COUNT(key) = 4
  ) AS k
  ORDER BY k.score_sum DESC;
```

This is my Statement, but my Database (postgresql) says that there is a syntax-mistake with my "AS".

But what ist the Problem? o.O I don´t understand

Comment: You can't define a alias for a subquery when in the `IN()` clause. And your subquery returns more than one column

Comment: To add to juergen's answer, you have to use a JOIN on the subquery to do what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need a join as in:

```
SELECT
  uri,
  sum(k.x) as score_x
FROM uris u
JOIN keywords k
ON u.id = k.id
WHERE k.key in ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4')
ORDER BY score_x DESC;
```

Not sure what you were trying to express with the HAVING COUNT(key) = 4 though.

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT u.uri, k.score_x
FROM uris u JOIN
     (SELECT id, SUM(x) AS score_x
      FROM keywords
      WHERE k.key in ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4')
      GROUP BY id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT key) = 4
     ) k
     ON u.id = k.id
ORDER BY k.score_sum DESC;
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this without a JOIN ? Is it possible to group by a table of the subquery, but do this in the top-level query. Because order-by in subquery have no effect.

Comment: @RayRayRay . . . I don't understand your comment.  There is no `order by` in a subquery in this answer.